# creating sql connection object once and using it several times

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

i'm creating login and register page in MVC asp.net but problem is that for each purpose i have to do all SQl connection, command, try open etc which really makes it slow so i as wondering that if i can get rid of creating ti again and again and just create sqlconnection thing once and calling it again and again for login, registration etc

```
namespace LoginSys.Models
{


    public class database
    {
        public ConnectionStatus connectDB(String name, String email, String pwd, String conStr)
        {
           // var con = conStr;
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCom.CommandText = "insert into tblRegister (userName, userEmail, userPwd) values (@name, @email, @pwd)";
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", pwd);
            ConnectionStatus connectStatus = new ConnectionStatus();
            int row_aff;
            try
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                row_aff = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connectStatus.Message = "OK";

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                connectStatus.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
            return connectStatus;


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are not creating a new physical connection to the database. ADO.NET uses a [`connection pool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This means that even if you create a new instance of SqlConnection, you are not actually creating a new physical connection but are drawing one from the pool. Also when you call the `.Close()` method you are not actually closing the underlying connection. You are just returning it to the connection pool so that it can be reused.

So your code won't be slow because of that.

The only improvement I may recommend you to this code is to wrap the `IDisposable` objects in `using` statements:

```
public ConnectionStatus ConnectDB(string name, string email, string pwd, string conStr)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCom = sqlCon.CreateCommand())
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        sqlCom.CommandText = "insert into tblRegister (userName, userEmail, userPwd) values (@name, @email, @pwd)";
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", pwd);

        ConnectionStatus connectStatus = new ConnectionStatus();
        try
        {
            sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connectStatus.Message = "OK";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            connectStatus.Message = ex.Message;
        }

        return connectStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok sir great but if i use USING then i won't need to place TRY FINALLY for closing resources but would i need try...catch to handle exceptions ? is USING able to replace those too ?

Comment: `using` is replacing the `try/finally`. If you wan't to handle some other database exception you could still leave the `try/catch` as shown in my answer. The `sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery()` method could throw an exception that we are catching and setting the `connectStatus.Message = ex.Message;`. The `using` statement will guarantee you that the `.Dispose` method will be invoked (the same way as you were doing with the `finally`).

Comment: ok so try....catch still has it's part to play in code and can't be replaced by using etc ? is it ?

Comment: Yes, exactly as it allows you to catch exceptions that occur during the execution of the SQL query and show some friendly message to the user. If you don't catch it, the exception will propagate.